# Reliably detecting keyup and keydown events triggered by combinations of Alt and Shift in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, keyboard-shortcuts, key-events

**Context:**

I have a menu on a web page. Each option in the menu changes the content on the page, but doesn't redirect to an entirely different page. I need to allow a user to use Alt+Shift+Up and Alt+Shift+Down as hotkeys to navigate the menu without the mouse.

While holding Alt+Shift, the user can press the arrow keys a few times to navigate to the desired menu option, and then select that option by releasing both Alt and Shift (it would also be fine if the menu option was selected when they release *either* Alt or Shift - my discretion).

**Problem:**

These issues appear in Internet Explorer. I haven't tested other browsers yet.

1. When you press and hold (**one at a time, in this specific order**) Alt+Shift, then release Alt first, and then Shift, no keyup events are registered at all - only keydown events for both keys.
2. When you press and hold Shift+Alt (**in that order**), and then release Alt, and then Shift, you get both keydown events, but only the Alt keyup event registers.
3. When you press and hold Alt+Shift (**in that order**), and then release Shift, and then Alt, you get both keydown events, but only the Shift keyup event registers.

How can I reliably detect when the user releases one or both of the Alt and Shift keys in Internet Explorer?

**Additional (possibly relevant) Details:**

When you press and hold Shift+Alt (**in that order**), and then release Shift, and then Alt, you get both keyup and keydown events.

**Demo:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
                console.log("key up");
            });
            document.addEventListener("keydown", function(){
                console.log("key down");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```